# Unit Testing a static method in a Java Class from Groovy Test case

Tags: java, grails, groovy, junit, mocking

I am trying to write a test case in groovy for a class that is written in java. The Java class(name:Helper) has a static method in it where a HttpClient object is obtained and executeMethod is called on it. To Unittest this class,I am trying to mock this httpClient.executeMethod() in groovy test case, but not able to mock it right.

Below is the Java class

```
public class Helper{

    public static message(final String serviceUrl){   

        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
        HttpMethod httpmethod = new HttpMethod();

        // the below is the line that iam trying to mock
        String code = httpClient.executeMethod(method);

    }
}
```

Any Ideas on how to unit test this static method from groovy. Since httpClient object is object inside the class method, how do i mock this object in groovy test case?

This is the test case that I have so far.I am trying to mock to null, but not happening...

```
void testSendMessage(){
    def serviceUrl = properties.getProperty("ITEM").toString()

    // mocking to return null   
    def mockJobServiceFactory = new MockFor(HttpClient)
    mockJobServiceFactory.demand.executeMethod{ HttpMethod str ->
        return null
    }

    mockJobServiceFactory.use {         
        def responseXml = helper.message(serviceUrl)

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
HttpClient.metaClass.executeMethod = {Type name -> doSomething}
```

You need to declare the closure signature with the correct `Type` i.e. String, Map, etc.

```
void testSendMessage(){
    def serviceUrl = properties.getProperty("ITEM").toString()

    // mocking to return null   
    HttpClient.metaClass.executeMethod = {HttpMethod str -> null}
    def responseXml = helper.message(serviceUrl)

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, did not understand what the closure is doing. I understand that executeMethod is being added to the metaclass of HttlpClient. Could you please explain the {Type name -> doSomething}. Also, updated the test case that I have written so far

Comment: The closure is replacing (mocking) the original code from `executeMethod` When you are executing your tests, the closure is executed instead the original code. Type name -> doSomething is only dummy example code. You need write the correct parameters types to get that closure executed.

Comment: hmmm....the above code does not mock it to null.httpClient.executeMethod(method) returns 200 but not null. I wonder if 
         HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
has anything to do with not being able to mock it.