# Mocking HttpClient in Groovy

Tags: java, grails, groovy, junit, mocking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unit Testing a static method in a Java Class from Groovy Test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218699/unit-testing-a-static-method-in-a-java-class-from-groovy-test-case)

I am trying to unit test a java class using groovy The `Helper` has a static method in it where an `HttpClient` is obtained and `executeMethod` is called on it. To unit test this class, I am trying to mock this `httpClient.executeMethod()` in a Groovy test case, but I'm not able to mock it right.

Below is the Java class

```
public class Helper{

    public static message(final String serviceUrl){   

        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
        HttpMethod httpmethod = new HttpMethod();

        // the below is the line that iam trying to mock
        String code = httpClient.executeMethod(method);

    }
}
```

Any Ideas on how to unit test this static method from Groovy? Since the `httpClient` object is inside the class method, how do I mock this object in a Groovy test case?

This is the test case that I have so far. I am trying to mock to null, but not happening...

```
void testSendMessage(){
    def serviceUrl = properties.getProperty("ITEM").toString()

    // mocking to return null   
    def mockJobServiceFactory = new MockFor(HttpClient)
    mockJobServiceFactory.demand.executeMethod{ HttpMethod str ->
        return null
    }

    mockJobServiceFactory.use {         
        def responseXml = helper.message(serviceUrl)

    }   
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://thecarlhall.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/unit-testing-with-httpclients-localtestserver/) helps you.

Answer (score 2):

A design where you're calling the HttpClient constructor explicitly from within a static method of a Java class is going to be very difficult to mock for testing. The Grails mocking facilities won't help because they can only mock calls that are within Groovy code, not Java. If your helper class were written in Groovy you might have more luck.

A better design would be to use a singleton service (or other Spring bean) with instance methods rather than statics, and use some kind of dependency injection, either of an HttpClient instance or of some kind of factory object that returns HttpClients. In the test you can then replace this factory with a mock one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ian. But the code above is in production already and hence not possible to change. Do you think its a better idea to write the test case for this java class in java, rather than groovy. If I am writing the test case in Java, could you please suggest me any approaches of mocking the httpclient call there?

Comment: You can still write your tests in Groovy but you'll need to use a pure Java mocking library such as JMockit rather than the Groovy-metaclass-based framework that Grails provides.

Comment: I can add JMOCKit to my grails project. Could you please show my some examples where this is being achieved using JMockit